# Ubuntu playsms unable to start

Tags: ubuntu, sms-gateway

i installed the playSMS software on ubuntu and for some reason it doesnt start. I get the rror unable to start playsmsd. I installed all the needed libraries. If someone had this problem i would appreciate if you'll help me.

Answer (score 1):

`playsmsd start` will starts 4 daemons (php scripts in background), they are: sendsmsd, recvsmsd, schedule and playsmsd.

running one of the script manually usually will popped up the real problem.

`/usr/bin/php -q /usr/local/bin/playsmsd sendsmsd`

what you want is above command will "hang", if there is error then it will be exit immediately and print the error

Comment: This helped me figure out my problem.  It threw an error that it could not connect to the DB.  The reason was that I did not set the DB password